# Git merge giving output "ALready up to date"

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm working in branch `A`, and earlier I did a `git merge B` where `B` is another local branch. I must have not properly merged or something because some of the changes from `B` are not present in `A`.

I tried `git merge B` again, and it outputs:

```
Already up to date.
```

but clearly there are changes from `B` that did not make it to `A`. Is it giving me this output because I did a merge previously with `B`? If so, how can I merge again?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like somebody did not properly merge those two branches.

Because the merge was done already and can't be merged again (because git doesn't see any changes since last merge),
it's probably best to make a new commit on top of A that fixes those mistakes and make the commit message say something like "Restore code of  lost in merge ".